Struggling to understand sets of equtions in Chern's paper "A simple intrinsic proof of the Gauss-Bonnet formula"
I'm struggling to understand an excerpt from Chern's paper A simple intrinsic proof of the Gauss-Bonnet formula for closed Riemannian manifolds:

According to Cartan we attach to each point $P$ of $R^n$ a set of $n$ mutually perpendicular unit vectors $e_1, \dots, e_n$, with a certain orientation. Such a figure $Pe_1 \dots e_n$ is called a frame. A vector $\mathbf{v}$ of the tangent space of $R^n$ at $P$ can be referred to the frame at $P$, thus
$$
\mathbf{v} = u_i e_i,
$$
where the index $i$ runs from $1$ to $n$ and repeated indices imply summation. The law of infinitesimal displacement of tangent spaces, as defined by the parallelism of Levi-Civita, is given by equations of the form
$$
\begin{aligned}
dP &= \omega_i e_i, \\
de_i &= \omega_{ij} e_j, \quad \omega_{ij} + \omega_{ji} = 0
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\omega_i$, $\omega_{ij}$ are Pfaffian forms. These Pfaffian forms satisfy the following "equations of structure":
$$
\begin{aligned}
d\omega_i &= \omega_j \wedge \omega_{ji}, \\
d\omega_{ij} &= -\omega_{ik} \wedge \omega_{kj} + \Omega_{ij}, \quad \Omega_{ij} + \Omega_{ji} = 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
In (3) $\Omega_{ij}$ are exterior quadratic differential forms and give the curvature properties of the space.

TLDR: what is the meaning of the last two sets of equations? Are they definitions or derivations?

Everything is fine until Chern mentions the parallelism of Levi-Civita. At that point he states equations involving $dP$ and $de_i$; as $P$ and $e_i$ are vectors (not forms), I'm already confused as to the meaning of the $d$ behind them.
If the $\omega_i$ are real functions (which I have speculated due to $dP = \omega_i e_i$), its differential would yield
$$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}dx^i,$$
yet I seem to be completely wrong. This is not done, and it is stated these are "Pfaffian forms". If by this a differential form is meant, it should be a $1$-form so as to take only the vector, but then
$$dP = \omega_i(e_i)$$
is a sum of real numbers, and so is $dP$. Is this what is meant?

Searching for "Pfaffian" in google yields a wikipedia page on real-valued functions on matrices; if related, I cannot see how. Searching for "infinitesimal displacement" yields quite a variety of results, not sure which -if any- are at use here.

You need to read and learn about the method of moving frames before starting Chern's paper. You can see stuff for surfaces in Section 3 of Chapter 3 of my differential geometry text (free in my profile). But maybe read a whole text. An accessible new one is by Jeanne Clelland. You can also read parts of Spivak Volumes 2, 3 or Chern/Chen/Lam's text.

For starters, the expression $dP = \sum\omega_i,e_i$ would be written as $dP = \sum \omega_i\otimes e_i$ in today's notation. You are not evaluating $\omega_i$ on $e_i$. They are dual basis vectors. The correct equation (for any tangent vector $v$) is $v=dP(v) = \sum\omega_i(v)e_i$, which is now clear since $\omega_i(v) = v\cdot e_i$.
